# Компилятор typescript выдает разные ошибки в окне браузера и в окне vscode

Tags: typescript

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][[image: ошибка в окне браузера][1]]Я пишу приложение на React + Typescript. После компиляции ошибок в окне моей IDE нет. При этом я вижу ошибки в окне браузера.На скриншотах 25 строчка файла в окне браузера и в IDE Подскажите в чем может быть причина, где искать проблему.

Comment: **Нельзя поймать кошку в темной комнате, если ее там нет**. Какая ошибка у вас в браузере и почему вы думаете, что это typecript(typescript при компиляции преобразуется в javascript)?

Comment: SwaD я добавил информации к вопросу. Может это прояснит ситуацию

Comment: Скорее всего, ваша IDE просто не видит ошибку, в то время, как компилятор как раз видит и ругается на это

Comment: Спасибо. Посмотрю настройки ide